# How to add WSSE security headers to large multipart SOAP messages?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

We have a Java web service that we're enhancing so the client can send up some extremely large messages to the server. To support these large attachments, we're using MTOM.

Unfortunately, we're also adding WSSE security information to our SOAP headers, and this is causing problems in combination with the extra-large SOAP messages.

Our code to attach WSSE security information is within a SOAPHandler, and looks like this:

```
public void addSecurity(String username, String password, SOAPMessageContext context) throws SOAPException {
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
    SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();

    SOAPElement security = null;
    if (header == null) {
        header = envelope.addHeader();
    }
    security = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", WSSE_NS_URI);
    context.getMessage().saveChanges();

    SOAPElement usernameToken
            = security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
    usernameToken.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
    SOAPElement usernameElement
            = usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
    usernameElement.addTextNode(username);

    SOAPElement passwordElement
            = usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
    passwordElement.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
    passwordElement.addTextNode(password);
}
```

The failure occurs in the statement `context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope()`. The context.getMessage() call appears to try to fetch the entire message, and since the message is huge, we get a heap space error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ByteOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteOutputStream.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.ByteOutputStream.write(ByteOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.flushBuffer(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:447)
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.write(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:191)
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.write(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:244)
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.ToStream.characters(ToStream.java:1623)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.characters(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1126)
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker.dispatachChars(TreeWalker.java:246)
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker.startNode(TreeWalker.java:416)
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker.traverse(TreeWalker.java:145)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:390)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:399)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getContentAsStream(SOAPPartImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getHeaderBytes(MessageImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.readAsSOAPMessage(SAAJFactory.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.readAsSAAJ(SAAJFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.saaj.SAAJFactory.read(SAAJFactory.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.toSAAJ(AbstractMessageImpl.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.readAsSOAPMessage(MessageWrapper.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.handler.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:70)
    at com.ciminc.compass.singleSignOn.basic.SsoCookieRequestAppender.addSecurity(SsoCookieRequestAppender.java:147)
```

Ideally I'd like to add my WSSE information to the SOAP header without pulling in the entire multi-megabyte SOAP message. Is that possible?

Let me know if I can provide any other information to clarify.